# Multiple RewriteRule in htaccess to avoid 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I’m building a website that works with an API to get all the information it displays.

I am using the following rewrite rule in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php/$1
```

In order to make any URL that looks like http://domainname.com/user/username not fall into a 404 and call instead the user.php file so that I can then grab the last part of the URL, fetch it to the API and display the results.

This is working fine. However now I need to do the same for another kind of URL that looks like http://domainname.com/collection/collectionname, so I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ collection.php/$1
```

I also tried a variety of flags at the end of the RewriteRules such as `[C]`, `[N]` and `[L]`, but none of them seem to be working and the results vary from internal server errors to both types of URL using the user.php file instead each type using the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. In case someone has the same issue, this is the correct way of handeling both cases:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ user.php/$1
RewriteRule ^collection/(.*)$ collection.php/$1
```